# Firebase-Swift: How to add every created user to a friends list when created?

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase

I am trying to create a social media app and in doing so I am trying to  create a friends list in my database. I have the general idea of how the database is going to be structured but need help in the actual code of it as I am fairly new to Swift development.

This is my current database structure:

> users
>
> > uid_0
> >
> > > name: "John"
> > >
> > > email: "john@gmail.com"
> >
> > uid_1
> >
> > > name: "Doe"
> > >
> > > email: "doe@gmail.com"
> >
> > uid_2
> >
> > > name: "User"
> > >
> > > email: "user@gmail.com"

Here's my sign up view controller code

```swift
import Foundation
import Firebase
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class SignUpVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cPassField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var SignUpButton: UIButton!

    var userUid: String!
    var email: String!
    var username: String!
    var password: String!
    var cPassword: String!
    var friends: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:))))
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if let _ = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "uid") {

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toLogin", sender: nil)
        }
    }

    func printAlert(Header: String, Message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: Header, message: Message, preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func createAccount (_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if password != cPassword {
            self.printAlert(Header: "Error", Message: "Passwords Do Not Match")
        }
        else{
            guard let email = emailField.text, let password = passField.text, let username = usernameField.text else {
                print("Form is not valid")
                return
            }

            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (res, error) in

                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    if let error = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code) {

                    switch error {
                        case .invalidEmail:
                            self.printAlert(Header: "Error", Message: "invalid email")
                        case .emailAlreadyInUse:
                            self.printAlert(Header: "Error", Message: "in use")
                        default:
                            self.printAlert(Header: "Error", Message: "Create User Error")
                    }
                }
                    return
                }

                guard let uid = res?.user.uid else {
                    return
                }

                //successfully authenticated user
                let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://messagingdemo-af075.firebaseio.com/")
                let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)
                let values = ["username": username, "email": email, "password": password]
                usersReference.child("friends").setValue(self.friends)
                usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

                    if let err = err {
                        print(err)
                        return
                    }

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toHome", sender: nil)

                })

            })
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to achieve a database structure that looks like this:

> users
>
> > uid_1
> >
> > > name: "John"
> > >
> > > email: "john@gmail.com"
> > >
> > > friends
> > >
> > > > uid_2: = true
> > > >
> > > > uid_3: = false
> >
> > uid_2
> >
> > > name: "Doe"
> > >
> > > email: "doe@gmail.com"
> >
> > uid_3
> >
> > > name: "User"
> > >
> > > email: "user@gmail.com"

I'm assuming that this is something where I'll have to add every created user id to every users friends list when a new user signs up. However, I don't get how to write that programmatically in swift and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a model class that represent the User by taking the piece of code you wrote in your View Controller.

For example (check the [Swift Structures and Classes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html) documentation) :

```swift
class User {
    var uID: String!
    var email: String!
    var name: String!
    var password: String!
    var friends: [String] = []
}
```

Then initialize a list of `User` in your View Controller.

```swift
var users: [User]
```

So the *User* model (in your database) looks pretty much the same except for the property `friends`. Since it is of type `[String]` (list of string), it should look like this:

*We assume that John has for friend "user2", "user4" and "user9".*

> **uID** : "uID_1"
>   **email** : "john@mail.com"
>   **name** : "John"
>   **password** : "..."
>   **friends** : ["uID_2", "uID_4", "uID_9"]

---

I won't go in the details but:
You could also do it another way, separate the friends list from the user.

> "uID_1" : ["uID_2", "uID_4", "uID_9"]
>   "uID_2" : ["uID_1", "uID_6"]
>   ...

... Just to say that there is many ways to do it...

Comment: okay so that's kinda how I have my code for the user class right now but I haven't been able to understand how to add a list to a data base. Right now, I have a table view set up where I see a list of all available users. When I tap on a cell, I know how to get the uID of the user but how do I append that user id to the friends list in the database.

Comment: currently I have this when creating a user:


                let values = ["username": username, "email": email, "password": password]
                and then I add values using:                 
                usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in...})

so how would I add an empty list when creating a user

Comment: I must say, after some research, that my answer wasn't suitable for Firebase. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45780954/8648550). I hope it can help you @RithvikRavikumar!

Comment: Thanks @Chxyz but I just migrated to cloud firestore LOL